# Cant See Data Inside of Section Tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to count how many buttons are on a page. And then later press them. However to access these buttons I have to go through an iframe, some generic (div) layers, and a region (section) layer.

I'm able to get through the iframe layer with

`driver.switch_to.frame("iframeID")`

but cant figure out how to gain access to elements within the secion layers.

html looks something like this:

```
<iframe id="iframeID" resize="" src="about:blank;" seamless="" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="height: 2135px;" xpath="1">
   #document
   <!document>
      <html>
         <head>...</head>
         <body>
            <section class="sectionC">
               <div class="divC">
                  <button type="button" class="buttonC" data-id="1234" style="">Done</button>
                </div>
            </section>
         </body>
      </html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to achieve with Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
len(soup.find_all('button', {'type' : 'button'}))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to press the buttons later too though. (sorry should have included that.)

Comment: Maybe this one?
`buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")`
Should return an array of all buttons.